# MacBook Pro 13” mid-2012 iSight cable port broken

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, webcam, motherboard

I accidentally ripped the iSight display port away from the motherboard on my MacBook Pro during a display replacement. I’m fine with working without a camera since the quality is bad anyway. The system boots up fine as far as I can tell.

However, I read somewhere that the later models require the iSight cable to regulate temperature, overheating if the iSight cable is not recognized. Is this also true for this MacBook Pro model? What problems would I run into during use if I didn’t fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no Mac that has a temperature sensor as part of the cable assembly nor a temperature sensor as part of the FaceTime camera.

However, I can tell you from direct first hand experience, there won’t t be any temperature related issues from a damaged FaceTime cable or camera.  If had the ripped off in the same manner to yours, cut and even purposely removed.  None caused any issues.